# Tailwind CSS columns not responsive in Mobile

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, css-grid, responsive

I am using Tailwind CSS and totally new to this. I have 3 columns in the page and when testing for tablets or mobile, the columns are collpasing on one another and a horizonatl scroll appears. I want them to fall one under another in smaller screen.I want to have 3 columns(Content1 , content2.1\2.2 , content 3.1\3.2) and in 2nd and 3rd columns suppose to be 2 rows.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 grid-rows-4">
 <div class="col-span-2 border border-solid border-gray-300 ">
  Content 1
 </div>
  <div class=" grid  gap-4">
    <div class="border border-gray-300 border-solid row-span-2">
     Content 2.1
    </div>    
    <div class="border border-gray-300 border-solid row-span-1">
     Content 2.2
    </div>     
  </div>
  <div class=" grid gap-4">
    <div  class="border border-gray-300 border-solid row-span-1">
     Content 3.1
    </div>
    <div class="border border-gray-300 border-solid row-span-2">
      Content 3.2
    </div>    
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: To make every div a single column you can just remove the `col-span-2` class from 'Content 1' div. Check the below code:

```html
<div class="grid grid-rows-4 gap-4 md:grid-cols-4">
  <div class="border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 1</div>
  <div class="grid gap-4">
    <div class="row-span-2 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 2.1</div>
    <div class="row-span-1 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid gap-4">
    <div class="row-span-1 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 3.1</div>
    <div class="row-span-2 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 3.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Old Answer:**

You didn't mention the grid column behavior for the responsive screen. The below code will work:

```html
<div class="grid grid-rows-4 gap-4 md:grid-cols-4">
  <div class="col-span-2 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 1</div>
  <div class="grid gap-4">
    <div class="row-span-2 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 2.1</div>
    <div class="row-span-1 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 2.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid gap-4">
    <div class="row-span-1 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 3.1</div>
    <div class="row-span-2 border border-solid border-gray-300">Content 3.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I just added `md:` before the `grid-cols-4`. The `md:` will make the `grid-cols-4` class only workable from medium size screens. Therefore it won't work on smaller sizes ( mobile/tablet ). And you will get the desired output.

Comment: This collapses  both  2nd and 3 rd column below the first one but I want all 3 in one column.

Comment: Then you can just remove the `col-span-2` class from 'Content 1' div. I have updated the code. You can check it out.